# rsync "cannot stat destination" suddenly occurring with job that was running fine for months?

Tags: rsync, lubuntu

I run a daily rsync backup of my /var/www folder to a share on a Windows 2022 server. It's been running fine for a few months, but in the last couple of days has started failing with the error below. No changes have been made to either the source or destination folders or their permissions.

Any idea why I'm suddenly seeing this, and how to fix it? I'm running Lubuntu 20.04

```
$ rsync -av "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"
sending incremental file list
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/media/server2022/web": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(660) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

Here is how the target folder is defined in fstab:

```
$ rsync -av "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"
//192.168.1.4/public /media/server2022 cifs credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,defaults,exec,,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=077,fmask=137 0 0
```

Comment: Is the server folder actually mounting successfully? What does `ls -l /media/server2022` show?

Comment: It has been mounting fine up to now

Answer (score 0):

After much hunting around, I modified the entry for this share in /etc/fstab to include the "users" option:

```
//192.168.1.4/public /media/server2022 cifs credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,defaults,exec,,uid=1000,gid=1000,users 0 0
```

It seems to have resolved the problem. I'm guessing that an Ubuntu update caused a problem with the way it was previously configured, as it had been working fine for several months using the original fstab configuration (as in my OP)